# How to show the Crystal Viewer with the Group Tree panel collapsed

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

By default, the Crystal Viewer on a Web Form shows its Group Tree panel expanded, even if not used. I would like the viewer to appear with the Group Tree panel collapsed by default. Can I do that and how?

Answer (score 1):

This link may be of some interest to you

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/207643/Hide-Report-Group-Tree-in-WPF

Alternatively you can hide it altogether with the following:

**[Visual Basic]**

```
CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree() = True
```

**[C#]**

```
crystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = true;
```

**[C++]**

```
crystalReportViewer1->DisplayGroupTree = true;
```

**[VJ#]**

```
crystalReportViewer1.set_DisplayGroupTree(true);
```

Comment: Surely if I *didn't* want a GroupTree, I would say `crystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = *false*;' I couldn't get your way to work: too many complications between Win and Web forms.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("[id$=panelHeader_close]").click();
  });
```

Comment: Your's seems perfect; technically quite correct. In fact, if I paste `$("[id$=panelHeader_close]").click();` into the console, the panel closes, but otherwise not. I also tried to put a timeout and still no success.